# Filter two multidimensional arrays based on key matches, but each array has different structure - Output to new merged array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to extract only array items that match on specific fields and then I need to merge the two into one array only containing the data I need.

I have two arrays, and their structure is like below. Only *product_count* s where CATEGORY_ID of Array #1 match the Key of Array #2 should be the output.

**Array #1:** - Many of Array #1 CATEGORY_IDs will not exist in Array #2 key field.

```
    0 => Array (4)
      0 => 3
      CATEGORY_ID => 10
      1 => 1
      product_count => 8
    1 => Array (4)
      0 => 4
      CATEGORY_ID => 111
      1 => 6
      product_count => 109
    ...
```

**Array #2:**

```
    10 => Category Name 1
    110 => Category Name 2
    8 =>  Category Name 3
    109 =>  Category Name 4
    111 =>  Category Name 5
    3 =>  Category Name 6
    132 =>  Category Name 7
   ...
```

**Final Output should look something like:** and I might be going about this all wrong, so I am open to any suggestions..

```
    10 =>   [0] => Category Name 1
            [1] => 8 // product_count
    111 =>  [0] => Category Name 5
            [1] => 109 // product_count
    ...
```

I am running a foreach() to extract product counts per category. As you can see my two arrays reflect this by the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do a foreach loop, I believe:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $part) {
    $new_array[$part["CATEGORY_ID"]] = array( $array2[$part["CATEGORY_ID"]], $part["product_count"] );
}
```

I think I got the gist of what you want.  I don't think there is an actual PHP function to do what you want, either.